# How to iterate WTForms FieldList with Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, wtforms

As the title says, here's what I've got:

```
form = F(obj = myobject)
myfieldlist= FieldList(FormField(form))

{% for subfield in form.myfieldlist %}
    {{ subfield.field }}
    {{ subfield.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

This outputs nothing, any ideas? Also, not entirely sure if FormField is required.
Thanks

Answer (score 17):

`FormField` takes a *class* not an instance:

```
class GuestForm(Form):
    email = TextField()
    vip = BooleanField()

class VenueForm(Form):
    name = TextField()
    guests = FieldList(FormField(GuestForm))
```

Then in your controller:

```
form = VenueForm(obj=myobject)
render("template-name.html", form=form)
```

In your template you will need to iterate over the FieldList field as if it was its own form:

```
{% for guest_form in form.guests %}
    <ul>
    {% for subfield in guest_form %}
    <li>{{ subfield.label }} {{ subfield }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried using your example in a test page and it doesn't display any fields. Is there another step to display the fields in a template that I may have missed?

Comment: Yes, you need an object with a `guests` property containing a list with one or more objects with `email` and `vip` properties.  Either that or you need to add a minimum number of entries to `FieldList` - so `VenueForm`'s `guests` property declaration would become `guests = FieldList(FormField(GuestForm), min_entries=1)` if you wanted at least one entry.

Comment: Hi Sean. I've come across a problem that relates to this question. Just wondering if you have any ideas why this would happen?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866680/wtforms-filedlist-stringfield-object-is-not-iterable-error